# getFeaturesByAttribute is not a function error

Tags: openlayers, angular7

I'm using openlayers to create a map app and trying to change a layer feature icon when I press a button.
I've seen some examples and they advised me to use this code

```
let feature = this.vectorLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute('id', 1);

feature.style = this.iconiSelected;
this.vectorLayer.redraw();
```

But I get the error **this.vectorLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute is not a function**
The feature already has an icon, but i want to change it when i press a button, is this the right way to do it, or is there any other way?

Comment: That code is for OpenLayers 2.  You are probably using OpenLayers 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
let feature = this.vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatureById(1);
feature.setStyle(this.iconiSelected);
```

See here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeatureById and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html#setStyle